# Traduzir a tag "random"

Tags: debate, status-recusado, tag-específica

Me deparei com a tag "random" hoje. Não acho que faça sentido a existência dessa tag em inglês no nosso site em português.

Ao buscar semelhantes, percebi que existe uma tag "números-aleatórios", mas essa é muito específica para ser um sinônimo.

Sugiro "aleatório" como substituta.

Comment: Nem todas as tags em inglês são más. Há palavras como *layout* e *random* que são mais percetíveis aos programadores do que as traduções.

Comment: @JorgeB. Você realmente implica com o _layout_, hein?

Comment: @Jorge B. Concordo que há palavras que realmente merecem uma versão em inglês porque não existe ou não é bem difundida uma tradução. Cast é uma dessas palavras. Layout também. Mas Random? Nunca vi alguém conversar sobre isso em português falando essa palavra em inglês.

Comment: Desde que surgiram os PCs no Brasil (anos 80), sempre usei e ouvi usar *random*... Talvez a geração 2000 seja diferente?

Comment: @brasofilo Provavelmente. Na faculdade e no trabalho eu só ouvi essa palavra em inglês quando a intenção era falar sobre nomes específicos de construções da linguagem. Uma palavra meio feia que eu já ouvi muito é "randômico".

Comment: @Pablo eu sou de Portugal e quando falamos com pessoas da área costumamos dizer "fazes um random [no código] e resolves isso", por exemplo.

Comment: @Math irrita-me muito a outra palavra :P