# As tags "random" e "números-aleatórios" são sinônimas?

Tags: debate

Descrição de [random](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/random):

> Utilize esta tag para perguntas pertinentes a números aleatórios ou pseudo-aleatórios.

Descrição de [números-aleatórios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n%c3%bameros-aleat%c3%b3rios):

> Utilize esta tag para perguntas pertinentes a números aleatórios ou pseudo-aleatórios.

Chegou-se a levantar a [discussão em 2015 a tradução de `random`](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4552/5878) para `números-aleatórios`, mas aparentemente apenas foi falado sobre manter o termo em inglês ou não, sem discutir se seriam sinônimos.

Não encontrei alguma utilização de `random` que não fosse para números [pseudo-]aleatórios.

O que acham?

Comment: E encontrou o oposto?

Comment: @Maniero acredito que também não. Em muitas perguntas, inclusive, é utilizada as duas tags.

Comment: Pra mim são sinônimos sim.

Comment: Pois é, se não forem já devemos pensar em descrições melhores.

Comment: Que tal colocar aleatoriedade como sinónimo em ambas e usá-la?

Comment: Todo [tag:números-aleatórios] é [tag:random] mas nem todo [tag:random] trata-se de [tag:números-aleatórios]. Certo?

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do meu conhecimento, são sinônimos, se é que pode-se chamar assim, visto que são idiomas diferentes, eu votaria por manter o `random` visto que é mais familiar a esta área.

Comment: Já penso diferente por estarmos em uma comunidade brasileira e essa não ser uma palavra "americanizada" no Brasil como "MilkShake" por exemplo. Uma vez que traduzido "Números aleatórios" para o inglês ficaria "Random numbers" e não apenas "Random" onde poderia abranger várias outras coisas randômicas e não apenas números.

Comment: @VictorLaio, mas se formos pensar desta forma então teremos de usar tudo em português, salvo pelas palavras sem tradução clara, mas por exemplo o comando `print` poderia ser trocado por `escrever`, ai entramos em um outro ponto que é as palavras "aportuguesadas" como o `printar`. Agora se utilizarmos o `randômico` no lugar do `random` e do `número-aleatório`, creio que faria mais sentido.

Comment: Randômico seria perfeito.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, claro. São sinônimos. Depende de como a pessoa escreve na hora de publicar o tópico, mas tanto faz, na prática.